# DataTables colReorder and individual Column searching

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using DataTables 1.10.4 with ColReorder plugin and individual column searching. All works fine, until I start moving the columns around.

If I do an initial search on column 0 using the  following code it works:

```
    // table filters
    $('#dtReference').on('keyup', function() {
    oTable
        .columns(0)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
   });
```

However, if I move column 0 to the right, position 1 then the above code doesn't reference the correct item. I have tried replacing the .columns(0) with the name of the column, but this has no effect.

So, my question is, how can I maintain the correct search on the correct column, when those columns positions move?

Answer (score 3):

you have to calculate new index of column after column was moving. Try to replace:

```
.columns(0)
```

by

```
.columns( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
```